# MongoTemplate database query, instead of in-service code, to get required data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, java-8, mongotemplate

I need to create a `mongotemplate` database query to get a specific number of elements into a list.
At the moment I just get all the elements with `findAll()`, and then I modify the obtained data using code that I have writen within the service class.

Initially, I have a `Laptop` class with fields `price::BigDecimal` and `name::String` and I use `findAll()` to get a list of them.

Then I put those in a `HashMap`, where `key` is the `name` field, sorted from most expensive to cheapest.

```
        Map<String, List<Laptop>> laptopsMap = laptopsFrom.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Laptop::getName,
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                            l -> l.stream()
                                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Laptop::getPrice).reversed())
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    ))
            );
```

So the results are like below:

```
[{"MSI", [2200, 1100, 900]},
 {"HP",  [3200, 900, 800]},
 {"Dell", [2500, 2000, 700]}]
```

Then, I use the code in the bottom of the question, to create a `Laptop` list with the following contents:

```
[{"HP", 3200},   {"Dell", 2500}, {"MSI", 2200}, 
 {"Dell", 2000}, {"MSI", 1100},  {"HP", 900},
 {"MSI", 900},   {"HP", 800},    {"Dell", 700}]
```

So basically, I iterate the map and from each key, I extract the next in line element of the list.

```
do {
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Laptop>> entry : 
        laptopsMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        List<Laptop> value = entry.getValue();
        finalResultsList.add(value.get(0));
        value.remove(0);
        if (value.size() == 0) {
            laptopsMap.entrySet()
                .removeIf(pr -> pr.getKey().equals(key));
        } else {
            laptopsMap.replace(key, value);
        }
    }
} while(!laptopsMap.isEmpty());
```

I instead of all this in-class code need to use a mongoTemplate database argument, but I cant seem to figure out how to create such a complex query. I have read material about `Aggregation` but I have not found anything helpful enough. At the moment, I have started putting a query together as shown below:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.limit(numOfLaptops);
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(Laptop.PRICE).gte(minPrice));
```

Comment: You may want post a sample document from the collection - it will be helpful for someone to understand your code.

Comment: Hi @prasad, the collection, is a collection of Laptop objects with fields "name::String", and "price::BigDecimal"

Comment: @prasad, thank you. Could you please provide a more concrete example?